# Django context processor not rendering from shell

Tags: python, django, django-3.2, django-shell

Using **Django 3.2**

Have defined few global variables like

*app/context_processors.py*

```
from app.settings import constants

def global_settings(request):
    return {
        'APP_NAME': constants.APP_NAME,
        'APP_VERSION': constants.APP_VERSION,
        'STATIC_URL_HOST': constants.STATIC_URL_HOST
    }
```

and in `settings.py` file

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'app.context_processors.global_settings',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Have used `APP_NAME` in the email template footer like

*account/emails.py*

```
def welcome_email(user):
  
    subject_file = 'account/email/welcome_subject.txt'
    body_text_file = 'account/email/welcome_message.txt'
    body_html_file = 'account/email/welcome_message.html'

    subject_text = get_template(subject_file)
    body_text = get_template(body_text_file)
    body_html = get_template(body_html_file)

    context = {
        'username': user.username,
    }

    subject_content = subject_text.render(context)
    body_text_content = body_text.render(context)
    body_html_content = body_html.render(context)

    to = [user.email]

    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject=subject_content,
        body=body_text_content,
        from_email='{} <{}>'.format('Admin', 'admin@example.com'),
        to=to,
    )
    msg.attach_alternative(body_html_content, 'text/html')
    msg.send()
```

*templates/account/welcome_message.html*

```
Hi {{ username }},

Welcome to the application.

{{ APP_NAME }}
```

When the email is sent from the web portal, the `APP_NAME` is rendered fine, but when the email send is initiated from the Django shell

```
python manage.py shell

> from account.emails import welcome_email
> welcome_email(user)
```

Then the `APP_NAME` is not rendered in the email.

**How the context processor can be rendered from the shell as well?**

Comment: What is the `welcome_email` function?... Please see [ask] and how to write a [mre].

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Updated question with the `welcome_email` function

Answer (score 1):

A context processor takes as input an `HttpRequest` object, hence for a context processor to be run when a templates `render` method is called a request is needed to be passed to it like `template.render(context, request)`. Your `welcome_email` function doesn't take request and naturally can't pass it.

If this function is called from some view all you need to do is take the request as an argument and pass it to the templates `render` method:

```
def welcome_email(user, request):
    ...
    subject_content = subject_text.render(context, request)
    body_text_content = body_text.render(context, request)
    body_html_content = body_html.render(context, request)
    ...
```

If it is called by some automated process which doesn't have a request object, well since your processor doesn't even need the request and the values you use are constant just pass them yourself from the function.